# How to implement multiple CompareTo methods?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a custom generic array/container and it has a sort method:

```
public void Sort()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
    {
        int min = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < Count; j++)
            if (Items[j].CompareTo(Items[min]) < 0)
                min = j;

        if (min == i) continue;
        T temp = Items[i];
        Items[i] = Items[min];
        Items[min] = temp;
    }
}
```

Items is an array of T objects.
T implements IComparable and has a CompareTo method:

```
public int CompareTo(object obj)
{
    if (!(obj is Player))
        return -1;

    Player player = (Player)obj;
    if (Name.CompareTo(player.Name) < 0)
        return -1;
    else if (Name.CompareTo(player.Name) == 0)
        return LastName.CompareTo(player.LastName);
    else
        return 1;
}
```

Player class has 3 properties: Name, LastName and Score.
This works fine to sort elements by name and last name, but now I need another container that should be sorted by score (a third property).
How can I implement two different comparison methods **without using List and built-in OrderBy, Sort methods**?

Is it possible to pass class properties into the Sort method somehow?

```
Container<Player> sortedByName = playerList.Sort(Name, LastName);
Container<Player> sortedByScore = playerList.Sort(Score);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should implement an `IComparer<T>`. You can then change your sort method to accept it:

```
public class PlayerNameComparer : IComparer<Player>
{
    public int Compare(Player x, Player y)
    {
        if (x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name) < 0)
            return -1;
        else if (x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name) == 0)
            return x.LastName.CompareTo(y.LastName);
        else
            return 1;
    }
}
```

And the modified Sort method:

```
public void Sort(IComparer<Player> comparer)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
    {
        int min = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < Count; j++)
            if (comparer.Compare(Items[j], Items[min]) < 0)
                min = j;

        if (min == i) continue;
        T temp = Items[i];
        Items[i] = Items[min];
        Items[min] = temp;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
collection.Sort(new PlayerNameComparer());
collection.Sort(new ScoreComparer());
```

Comment: So does this mean I have to create a new class for each comparison? Is there a way to do this all inside a single PlayerComparer class?

Comment: You could accept a "Mode" parameter (an enum for example) when you construct the comparer, and work out the results of the comparison based on that, if you like.

Comment: There is another possibility, as the `Sort` page hints: a delegate (which is basically the same idea as `IComparer`, just more compact).

Answer (score 8):

Don't use `IComparable`. This will create objects that know how to compare themselves, always using the same criterion.

Instead, make an external [`IComparer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icomparer-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) - two, in fact! One that knows how to compare two players by names, and one that knows how to compare them by score.

You can see how to use it with standard `Sort` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=netframework-4.7.2). Or you can put it to use in your own `Sort` method, by replacing `Items[j].CompareTo(Items[min])` with `comparer.Compare(Items[j], Items[min])`